# Starting thin server without the thin gem does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, thin, faye

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.2. Every time i use the thin server with private_pub gem it does not work i did rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production. I get the following error

```
/home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:269:in `server'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
rzaartz@ubuntu:~/paper$ rvm 1.9.3
rzaartz@ubuntu:~/paper$ rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
/home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:269:in `server'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    from /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
```

but it i include the thin gem in my gem file it would work fine. Any help thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't start linux without linux.

You can't launch a rackup server without Rack.

You can't launch thin without thin gem.

Comment: i checked a tutorial by ryan bates and in his source code he did not include the thin gem

Comment: but he had thin install on this gem repository

Comment: `rackup -rubygems private_pub.ru -s thin -E production` and you need stop using Bundler

Comment: still no luck unless i add the thin gem in my gem file

Comment: @UchennaOkafor Then just add it to the Gemfile! Why are you trying to complicate things that are straight forward?

Comment: It's related to the thin upgrade to 1.4.1 (https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/115). This is probably why it works for the old Railscast but not now.

Answer (score 14):

```
/home/dimas/RUBY/application/faye-tutorial/faye.ru:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    from /home/dimas/RUBY/application/faye-tutorial/faye.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
```

I have the same problem. fix it with:

add this gem to Gemfile

```
gem 'faye'
gem 'thin'
```

then **bundle install**.

Comment: Many who find this are probably using Rails 4 / Ruby 2, and following Ryan Bate's railscast #260 on faye. 

`$ rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production`

He doesn't have `faye` or `thin` in the gem file. Despite doing a `gem install` on both `faye` and `thin`, @ least for Rails 4, `faye` & `thin` need to be in the gem file and a `bundle install` executed before the server will start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a gem, it must be in your `Gemfile`. You can solve your problem as follows:

- Add the following line to your `Gemfile`: `gem 'thin'`
- Update your current app's environment: `bundle install`
- Start the web server: `bundle exec thin start`